# Launch application from browser (Custom protocol? aos:\\)

Tags: html, browser, launch

Sorry if this is a way overused question, but I'm wondering how you would launch a program from a browser. Ace Of Spades (the game) does this with link beginning with 'aos://'. How might I implement this?

Comment: take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, that works for IE. But what about chrome and safari?

Comment: That's changing the browser's registry settings, its adding a protocol. You have to configure to OS to points aos:\\ to what ever you want it to can be a socket, application...

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you quite understand what I mean. When I register 'aos' as a protocol in the registry and then type aos://blah into Internet Explorer, it works. But it does not in Chrome and other browsers.